# Hidden char StringTokeneizer/split in Java?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have a text file and each of its line is like that

```
author-title-kind
```

I have a Java program parsing this file and it must returns only the books whose author is `"example"`.
I read a line at a time, and then I split the string with `StringTokeneizer` or `split()`.
So I will get 3 items: `author, title, kind`.
Then I check if the first item string is equal to "example".
The problem is that I always get false, and never true.
Is there any hidden character so that this comparison ends always with false?
Maybe I should check with `"example-"`, or `"-example"`...or anything else?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Are you comparing strings with `==` or with `"example".equals(yourData)`? If with `==` then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) should interest you.

Comment: Also, did you try to print individual string variables after split to see how they are split exactly?

Comment: If you are developing on an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans, or Intellij, try putting some breakpoints and debugging to see what values your tokens contain.

Comment: Yes, I am using Eclipse and I have tried all you've said. I print in terminal item[1], the author, and "example" and I see they appear totally equal. That's why I was wondering about an hidden char

Comment: Could you [[edit]] your question and add code which shows how you compare these values?

Comment: I've just solved. As suggested by you, it is necessary to do string1.equals(string2) to verify the two string are equal. Instead I used =...still so bad influenced by python

Answer (score 1):

Remember that String.split() takes a regular expression as a separator and not just a string. I would use apache commons StringUtils.split() if you want basic string splitting with a simple string.

Comment: How will that affect the splitting in this case. OP just needs to split on `-`, which is only special when used in a character class, that too between two characters.

Comment: True. I guess the OP needs to show his code and text file as well.